# Can the "Welcome - Stay in touch with colleagues and friends" message on LinkedIn home page be removed?

Tags: linkedin

Is there a way to remove the "Welcome - Stay in touch with colleagues and friends message" on LinkedIn's home page.

Comment: Is your profile at 85-100% completion ? Also how active are you ?

Comment: Yes, 85% and quite active now, post most days.

Comment: Can you post a screen shot? I can't see such a message on my account, but it would be helpful if I knew where to look.

Comment: @ChrisF It is a message you get when you now start to use LinkedIn appears above recent activity. @Scott Approx. How many connections do you have now ?

Comment: @phwd - cheers, I've been using it for a few years now & have a reasonable number of connections.

Comment: @ChrisF :) I was asking Scott XD about the connections because there might be quota that must be filled (10-15 connections maybe) to remove the message

Comment: 10 connections to date,

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [user style](http://userstyles.org/styles/33490) to hide it.

Comment: This is probably the best way. There seems to be some Javascript in place for manipulating the box, but I can't see where it's being called from.